# can you get the pc user name in vbs?

Tags: vbscript

Is there  way to find the PC user in visual basic (C:\User\"here").
After we get it, just save it as a string.

I know the answer might be a bit obvious, but I cannot find out how to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly simple, from here ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/03/11/how-to-get-the-user-running-a-vbscript.aspx )

```
Dim networkInfo
Set networkInfo = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork") 

Dim infoStr
infoStr = "User name is     " & networkInfo.UserName & vbCRLF & _
          "Computer name is " & networkInfo.ComputerName & vbCRLF & _
          "Domain Name is   " & networkInfo.UserDomain

MsgBox infoStr
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way might be to query the environment.

There are `USERDOMAIN`, `USERNAME`, `USERPROFILE` and `COMPUTERNAME` environment variables containing the obvious values.

Querying those would depend solely on `WScript.Shell` instead of on `WScript.Network` as in the accepted (and correct) answer. If you already have a reference to the shell, this might be a slightly more comfortable way.